# Connection with mongoose in express

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoDr5.png)

Here's the image

Can someone help me with the code?
thank you

Comment: Please share your code of how you're connecting application with MongoDB

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 2):

The issue is fixed when I turn Admin privileges on in Mongodb Atlas.